# Каждая цифра в числе меньше предыдущей – возможно ли через CHECK?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, sqlite, sqlite3

Как в SQLite разрешить для столбца только числа, в которых каждая цифра (кроме первой) меньше предыдущей?

Comment: Что значит "как"? написать соответствующее выражение в CHECK. Получится, конечно, монструозненько... так что лучше триггером.

Comment: @Akina, значит, какой алгоритм выражения, что именно писать? Хотя, я уже догадываюсь про такой вариант: определить количество цифр с помощью length, и для каждого количества – свой набор сравнений между вырезанными функцией substr цифрами.

Comment: @Akina, ещё интересно, с помощью регулярного выражения никак нельзя сравнить символы строки между собой?

Comment: Я ж вроде сказал - делайте лучше триггером. Дешевле будет. *интересно, с помощью регулярного выражения никак нельзя сравнить символы строки между собой?* Регулярные выражения не оперируют кодами символов (что необходимо для сравнения). Там вообще функций нет.